# Google Cloud Dataflow fails in combine function due to worker losing contact

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My Dataflow consistently fails in my combine function with no errors reported in the logs beyond a single entry of:

```
 A work item was attempted 4 times without success. Each time the worker eventually lost contact with the service.
```

I am using the Apache Beam Python SDK 2.4.0. I have tried performing this step with both CombinePerKey and CombineGlobally. The pipeline failed in the combine function in both cases. The pipeline completes when running with a smaller amount of data.

Am I exhausting worker resources and not being told about it? What can cause a worker to lose contact with the service?

**Update:**

Using `n1-highmem-4` workers gives me the same failure. When I check Stackdriver I see no errors, but three kinds of warnings: `No session file found`, `Refusing to split`, and `Processing lull`. My input collection size says it's 17,000 elements spread across ~60 MB, but Stackdriver has a statement saying I'm using ~25 GB on a single worker which is getting towards the max. For this input, each accumulator created in my CombineFn should take roughly 150 MB memory. Is my pipeline creating too many accumulators and exhausting its memory? If so, how can I tell it to merge accumulators more often or limit the number created?

I do have an error log entry verifying my worker was killed due to OOM. It just isn't tagged as a worker error which is the default filtering for the Dataflow monitor.

The pipeline definition looks something like:

```
table1 = (p | "Read Table1" >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=query))
     | "Key rows" >> beam.Map(lambda row: (row['key'], row)))
table2 = (p | "Read Table2" >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=query))
     | "Key rows" >> beam.Map(lambda row: (row['key'], row)))

merged = ({"table1": table1, "table2": table2}
     | "Join" >> beam.CoGroupByKey()
     | "Reshape" >> beam.ParDo(ReshapeData())
     | "Key rows" >> beam.Map(lambda row: (row['key'], row)))
     | "Build matrix" >> beam.CombinePerKey(MatrixCombiner())  # Dies here
     | "Write matrix" >> beam.io.avroio.WriteToAvro())
```

Comment: 1) did you see any errors in your stackdriver logs? 2) Could be you are running our of memory etc. A quick try can be attempted by using a worker type with high memory `--machine_type=n1-highmem-8`. see all types: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#highmem. If it solves your problem, you know where to improve.

Comment: I'll update post with some details. It looks like it is memory related, but I'm not sure what's causing the blow up

Comment: Actually what is the step before the combine logic? Could it explode before you enter the combine step? It might help to briefly have some of your code samples.

Comment: I just key the data to get it ready for the combine. The dataflow monitoring tool says that step reached completion before the job died. I'll post a simplified version of the code.

Comment: yay, looks like the culprit is your combiner. what happens inside `MatrixCombiner`?

Comment: I don't know if I can write a simplified version of that. It's using numpy to get some statistics about the data. The accumulator is a Python list of 5 elements - 4 `np.float32` numpy arrays and one `int`. The memory bottleneck should have formula `max(n*150 MB, 150 MB + 4*6000*nrows MB)` where the first entry is `merge_accumulators`, n the number of accumulators and the second is `add_inputs` with an accumulator and an intermediate that depends on the number of rows passed.

Comment: Oh that should be Bytes for the intermediate. Also I don't know how beam organizes its work. You might need to add the two `max` options in different combos if there are steps happening concurrently and temp copies might get made during the course of calculations.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It looks like it was the number of accumulators created. I added some metrics to track accumulator creation. Running with fewer workers leads to less accumulators and successful completion of the pipeline.

Comment: Good to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

Running with fewer workers leads to less accumulators and successful completion of the pipeline.

Comment: Your answer looks like Ctrl-C + Ctrl-V from comments

Comment: I think it's an attempt to indicate that there *is* an answer to the problem - that's why it was made "community wiki". I suspect though that the OP could improve the answer.