# Google cloud dataflow provide memory hints to pipeline

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My pipeline creates large intermediate arrays inside a `CombineFn`. When I run with a small number of workers the pipeline succeeds. When I raise the number of workers the pipeline fails due to OOM errors on the workers during this step. I'm not entirely sure why this happens, but my best guess is that the dataflow underestimates the amount of memory needed in the add_input step and creates too many accumulators.

Is there some way I can provide hints to the pipeline, saying something like each accumulator needs X MB of memory?

I posted about this problem before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50417540).

I am now using Apache Beam Python SDK 2.7, but the problem remains.

Comment: I don't know if that is possible. Unfortunately the only way to know what is going on behind the scenes is to pay for GCP support. But Dataflow Transforms are meant to be simple bite-size steps. Each accumulator being 150 MB is problematic. You need to somehow redesign your pipeline, maybe split up your CombineFn into multiple CombineFns that run in parallel, each one only tries to calculate one stat. Maybe some iteration that you are doing inside your Combine could be done as part of the pipeline.

Comment: The same intermediate array gets used for calculating every value. I don't think spreading the work out would reduce peak memory usage. Although now that you mention it, I override `add_inputs` and make `add_input` call it. Using just `add_input` would be less efficient but would help memory usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by creating and then immediately deleting an array a little bigger than the size of my intermediate in the `add_input` function. Without knowing Google's internals it's hard to say why that worked and if I continue to increase the number of workers it's possible I could run into the same issue again. But give that a try if anyone else runs into the same issue.